# Receiving Compile Error: Invalid qualifier on Range Object

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving the error message 'compile error: invalid qualifier' in the second last line of the below code.

```
Dim Init_Range() As Range
Dim Init_Mod_Range() As Range

Init_Range = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange
Init_Mod_Range = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange

Init_Range.Select
Selection.Clear
```

I am sure that I'm able to select a range, because if I switch to the below line of code, it works.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.Select
Selection.Clear
```

Can anyone tell me why assigning the range to a variable breaks the code? Perhaps I should be using a different variable type? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Set

```
Set Init_Range = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange

Set Init_Mod_Range = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange
```

You need to use Set when dealing with Object references, you can just use = for assignment when dealing with simple data types but objects such as ranges and worksheets need Set.

Also I don't think you need the () when you declare Init_Range, this will declare an array of ranges, it appears you only intended it to be a single range.

Answer (score 0):

Object variables like ListObjects and Ranges need to be set first before you can use .Select or other variations:

```
Set Init_Range = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange
```